# Ignore vlan tagged packets on primary interface

Tags: vlan

I have an Ubuntu VM on ESXi with a single network interface which is a port group tagged as VLAN 4095 so it has access to all tagged VLANs.  The native VLAN is 37.
I've created several vlan interfaces using Netplan like this:

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  vlans:
    vlan98:
      id: 98
      link: ens160
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      link-local: []
```

I have a service receiving multicast traffic on all interfaces, including the primary `ens160`, and I want the traffic to remain separate for each interface.  The problem I'm facing is:  `ens160` receives *all* packets, including tagged ones.  Is there a way to make this primary interface *only* see untagged packets?

```
# ip -d link show
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:07:84:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 13 minmtu 60 maxmtu 9000 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
25: vlan98@ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:07:84:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 minmtu 0 maxmtu 65535 
    vlan protocol 802.1Q id 98 <REORDER_HDR> addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Example showing the packet I would like to exclude:

```
# tcpdump -ni ens160 -e host 10.37.154.4
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens160, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:55:00.023677 00:60:74:fb:d0:87 > 01:00:5e:00:01:81, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 90: vlan 98, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.37.154.4.319 > 224.0.1.129.319: UDP, length 44
```

I tried disabling dhcp on ens160 and then adding an additional interface for vlan37 but that brings networking down entirely.

Comment: A normal IP multicast application has no reason to receive VLAN tagged traffic if it's able to select a specific interface such as ens160 (rather than receiving from anything): that's not IP so it's ignored at IP layer 3 by the routing stack. *tcpdump* is not a normal application, it captures using an AF_PACKET socket so does see this traffic. So can you explain why you still need this? This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The application I'm using is ptpTrackHound.  It does see tagged traffic on the primary interface.  Based on your explanation, I'm _guessing_ maybe it also uses AF_SOCKET.  My goal is for this app to see PTP traffic on each VLAN and keep them separated.